# How to have specific maven goal appear on Life-cycle or plugins without run configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project, in my pom.xml file, I'm using org.codehaus.mojo
I have generated an option to run the main class with a synonym name:

```
mvn exec:java@genSql
mvn exec:java@runSql
```

I would like these goals to appear under Maven LifeCycle/Plugins just like Clean, instal, etc.

I don't want to use Maven run configuration since it's not on git
How do make it shown on the Lifecycle or Plugins?

```
   <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>genSql</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.myCompany.build.SqlGenerator</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>runSql</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.myCompany.build.DBLauncher</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you want

Comment: Related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119327.

Comment: @Jens I believe the question is how to add the goal to IntelliJ or Eclipse. For Eclipse you right-click the project, go to `Run As` -> `Run Configurations...`, double-click the `Maven Build` and customize your goals. Never used IntelliJ, though.

Comment: How would you prevent from each developer need to adding it manually ?